# Creating a homogeneous system of linear equations that has no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I was given a question related to finding a $\lambda$ value for a homogeneous system of linear equations not to have any solution. This $\lambda$ was among the coefficients matrix (if considering the matrix form of the system $AX=0$).

I immediately thought of the affirmation that is it not possible because for any given homogeneous system it will always have the trivial solution $X=0$.

My question: My affirmation is true? and if so, Is there a way to prove it or is something completely unnecessary and pointless?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming that by "homogeneous system" you mean that $Y=0$ then you are correct: $X=0$ is always a solution. Perhaps the question is mistaken. Perhaps they meant "no NONTRIVIAL solution" ?

Comment: @Simon I asked and I was told that the question is right.

Comment: In which case there is no such condition on $\lambda $.

Comment: @Simon Yeah I thought the same, Just that I wasn't sure if the affirmation was true.